# Eviews- Error correction estimation using BDM's one-step procedure

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive, ecm

I am trying to estimate an equation for the average wage using quarterly data. I want to build an ECM which can bes estimated using Banerjee-Dolado-Mestre's approach to cointegration. So far, I haven't found yet the correct specification of my model. The model I'm running in EVIEWS is

```
d.logaveragewage_t=c+b_1*d.logcpi_t+b_2*d.unemployementrate_t+b_3*d.logproductivity_t+a_1*logaveragewage_t-1+a_2*logcpi_t-1+a_3*logproductivity_t-1+e_t
```

I tried adding some lags for my first differenced variables but that didn't check. 
I also tried to add a term assuming the error follow an AR(1). This gave me the results I want but I don't know how accurate is it to do this. Do you think it is correct to do so?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is the [tag:vecm] tag relevant here?

Comment: Probably not. Sorry for that. That's my first time on this website.

Comment: No problem, that is an easy fix.